# CAST, SUM, CASE Issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I am trying to accommodate for some rogue values in my database, that contain the string 'unknown', I want to set these to 0 and then sum the rest. But for some reason, this isnt happening. Here is what I have -

Values - VARCHAR(30) -

```
     3
     0.1
     2
     16
     2
     5
     2
     Unknown
     2.4
     7
     Unknown
```

And here is my Cast,Sum,Case

```
Cast(sum(case when stake = 'Unknown' then 0 else stake end) as float) as totalStake
```

But I get this error - Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '0.1' to data type int.

Help!

Thanks

Comment: Why are you storing numerical data as a `varchar` in the first place? There are so many problems with storing numerical data as the wrong data type. For example with a `varchar` `'2'` is **greater than** `'199'`, and `'1'+'2'` equals `'12'`. You should really be fixing your datatype here.

Answer (score 3):

You must cast stake as a float:

```
sum(case when stake = 'Unknown' then 0.0 else cast(stake as float) end) as totalStake
```

Answer (score 1):

You should explicitly convert to some sort of numeric values.  Try this:

```
sum(try_convert(numeric(18, 4), stake)) as totalStake
```

Your code has at least two issues.  First, your `case` expression returns an integer (because the first `then` has an integer).  So, it tries to convert `stake` to an integer, which can generate an error.

Second, you should be doing arithmetic operations on data that is *explicitly* some sort of number type and not rely on implicit conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Initial step would be to replace the 'Unknown' string with 0 using a replace function and then convert the column datatype to the one which allows to perform Aggregate functions and then perform SUM on top of that. The below query will work only for 'unknown' string, if you have different strings other than 'unknown' you might have to choose a different approach like using IsNumeric in Replace function and update the string value to 0.

```
select sum(cast((REPLACE(stake,'unknown',0))  as float)) from table
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following query using i`snumeric()` to check numeric data.

```
create table temp (stake VARCHAR(30))
insert into temp values
('3'), ('0.1'), ('2'), ('16'), ('2'), ('5'), ('2'), ('Unknown'), ('2.4'), ('7'), ('Unknown')

--Select * from temp

Select sum(Cast(stake as Float)) from temp where isnumeric(stake) = 1
```

To handle some exception like `null` values or `.` values only you can try this

```
Select SUM(TRY_CAST(stake as Float)) from temp
```

You can find the live demo [Here](https://rextester.com/ORJMS36308).

Comment: I recommend against `isnumeric`. Considering the OP has values like `'Unknown'` in a column that is supposed to have numerical data, I wouldn't put it past them to have values like `'.'`; which will cause this SQL to error. `TRY_CONVERT` and `TRY_CAST` are far more reliable functions. `ISNUMERIC` can, and does, provide wrong answers.

Comment: @Larnu but U you can't insert Unknown in other data type column.

Comment: *" which will cause this SQL to error."* @Larnu see [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=adefca41cde9e2f52ac7504d7fa28c44)  i don't see SQL server 2017 error when using `isnumeric("Unknown")`

Comment: Yes, because the OP *should* be using `NULL` to represent an "unknown value". That is **exactly** what a `NULL` is.

Comment: *"the OP should be using NULL to represent an "unknown value". That is exactly what a NULL is."* @Larnu that i agree on

Comment: @RaymondNijland try `SELECT CASE ISNUMERIC('.') WHEN 1 THEN CONVERT(decimal(12,2),'.') END` or `SELECT CASE ISNUMERIC('1.0') WHEN 1 THEN CONVERT(int,'1.0') END` Notice these both return errors. Also note that `ISNUMERIC('')` returns 0, however, `CONVERT(int,'')` returns `0`, as the value is successfully converted. `ISNUMERIC` doesn't mean that the value will (or won't) convert.

Comment: @Larnu I don't think only . (dot) is a decimal value.

Comment: @Larnu ok got it.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because SQL has some problems while converting decimal values to integer values.
In facts, function `sum` returns integer values

[image]

I solved it using round function on the values1 variable ( sorry for using same name for table and column ):

```
 select Cast(sum(case when values1 = 'Unknown' then 0 else round(values1, 2) end)  as 
 float)as totalstrike
 from values1
```

Comment: *"This happens because SQL has some problems while converting decimal values to integer values."* SQL Server doesn't have any problems converting a `decimal` to a `int`; what it can't do is convert a `varchar` representation of a `decimal` to a `int`. The reason `SUM` is returning an `int` here (in the OP's question), is because that is the datatype returned by the `CASE` expression, and so `SUM` returns an `int`: [SUM (Transact-SQL) - Return Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#return-types).

Comment: Yes Maybe i expressed myself in a wrong way, i wanted to say what you are saying